# Error in Java Import statement "The import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull cannot be resolved"

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-roo

After developing Spring roo project, I found following errors in class:

```
The import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull cannot be resolved

NotNull cannot be resolved to a type
```

I am using `STS 3.1.0.RELEASE`

How can this be rectified?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The jar containing this class must be added to the build path of your project: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api/1.0.0.GA

Comment: Then it says "Overriding managed version 1.1.0.Final for validation-api"? What do I do

Comment: springboot already declares this dependency. This solution didn't work in my case.

Answer (score 121):

I had the same problem. I found out that the recent versions of `Spring Boot` need a separate dependency for `validation`. I tried adding the below dependency in the `pom.xml` file and it worked.

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId> 
</dependency>
```

Comment: This solved the error that I got after upgrading Spring Boot to 2.4.1 from 2.2.5.RELEASE

Comment: this solves the problem, just added the dependency and refreshed maven. Intellij

Comment: I've found this error after upgrade spring boot to 3.0.2 from 2.6, solved after add this dependency

Answer (score 22):

for JDK-9 the old version of "javax.validation" is not supporting. So we should add latest version.

we will know the latest version of any jar the following way

```
C:\Users\username\.m2\repository\javax\validation\validation-api
```

The above folder should have all versions of the jar, then you can add the latest version as dependency in the pom.xml file the following way

In my case "2.0.0.final" is the latest version.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I updated according to my latest version and yet the problem is persistent.

Comment: New Version: 2.0.1.Final

Answer (score 16):

from Spring boot 2.3 version you have to add this dependency in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

the web starters no longer contains the validation so you have to add it manually

Answer (score 12):

If you are using SpringBoot and you are migrating to **Spring Boot 3**, you need to replace all your references of javax.validation with jakarta.validation.

Check the release notes of Spring Boot:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Release-Notes

Answer (score 8):

Im using JDK JAVA 8 and i still had a similar problem. The error disappeared just by adding the following Sample in my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

The following artical helped me find the solution:
"https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation"

Answer (score 2):

I was dealing with same problem.

Here you need to import like this -
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;

Instead of -
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull

and also add the following dependency in your pom.xml file.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to copying and pasting .jar en `<root-project>/lib` you also have to add them in **Project Structure > Libraries > Classes**

GL

[Hibernate Validator](https://hibernate.org/validator/)

Answer (score 1):

Before, Gradle included this dependency by default. I don't know what happen. You have to add manually this dependence: implementation 'jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:2.0.2'

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use Jakarta validation instead of javax. As the latter is considered legacy already. Spring Boot 3 includes Jakarta lib by default.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and I simply downloaded API from 
: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api/1.0.0.GA
: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/com.springsource.javax.validation/1.0.0.GA

It started to work -))))))))

Answer (score 0):

**Intellij solution:**
After pasting the code below you need to close intellij (entirely) then open again.

pasted the following:

```
    <dependency>
         <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
         <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
         <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

there are also following versions there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using gradle, in "build.gradle" file add the following in the "dependencies"

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'

testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem, I added the following dependency **org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation** but still had the same error. Then found that there has been change due to a migration from **javax** to **jakarta**
You need to change your imports from

javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

to

import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;