# which hibernate version i should use?

Tags: hibernate, spring-integration, integration

> i have downloaded hibernate release 5.4.4 final and in eclipse i have build in path these jars but in that don't have hibernate validator jar and i need it can anyone suggest me that which version i have to download or i have to download hibernate validator separately?
>   Actually i have a class that class have parameter like name,email and password on which i want to use annotation like notblank email formate etc by using 5.4.4 version i am not getting these annotation and i have mention in above line that in 5.4.4 version these is no hibernate validator jar so please suggest me that which version i should download so that i can use these addition annotation too
>   if appreciable if anyone can provide me the link of appropriate version Thank you

**see the screen shots**

> I am not using maven and adding my jars manually
>   This how i have added hibernate validator,hibernate core jars in build path does it correct or not?
>
> hibernate validator jar with bean and anntotion 
>   [image: hibernate validator]
>   hibernate core jar with controller class[image: hivernate core jar orm]
>   spring jar [image: spring jar]
>   **Error console**
>   error console in eclipse`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.validation.constraints.Pattern$Flag`[image: eclipse console]
>   **error on browser side when i make request to application saying**`javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: [Ljavax/validation/constraints/Pattern$Flag;
>   [![browser error][5]][5]`
>   **please help me to fix this error thank you**

Answer (score 0):

You could download the hibernate-validator for eclipse using this link https://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernate/files/hibernate-validator/6.1.5.Final/

Comment: does it also contains all basic hibernate jar? or i have to download other jar also individually #Sanju Keshavan

Comment: This contains only the hibernate validator dependencies. You could get other hibernate jars from its ORM dependency https://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernate/files/hibernate-orm/5.4.17.Final/

Comment: if i am using hibernate validator 6.1.5 final and if i use hibernate ORM different version jar then it will work? or i have to download same version of hibernate validator and hibernate ORM jar

Comment: It should work with different version of hibernate validator and orm dependencies. You could refer this [link](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-validator-constraints)

Comment: sir i have gone through the link you gave in which article they have added dependencies via pom.xml that is maven project example but in my case i am not using maven just simply i have download the jar files of validator and ROM please share the link or idea that how we can integrate hibernate and spring without maven

Comment: i have added the screen shots of my issues in my post please have a look Sanju keshavan

Comment: @siddhantsahani here is a reference [link](http://javaonlineguide.net/2015/03/spring-4-and-hibernate-4-integration-example-project-in-eclipse-without-maven-support.html) on how to use hibernate with spring without maven. though its for a bit older version, i guess it could still guide you.

Comment: For the exception you mentioned in the screenshot may be possibility of validation-api jar conflict. You may refer this issue for more clarity on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26637800/classnotfoundexception-javax-validation-validatorfactory)